# Trying to remove item from webpage after "purchased" but still displays in users purchased items history

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have three tables - ItemTable, UserTable, TransactionTable.

The items are pulled form the database and listed on the website. When the user views the item they click on the "buy" buttons which triggers the buy.php script to run. This script inserts the data into the TransactionTable. It has transID(PK) then inserts itemid(FK-item table) sellerid(FK-userTable) and buyerid(FK-UserTable).

This all works successfully. However when this insert occurs I want the item to be removed form the main webpage, however I would still like it to be available in the users purchaseditems.php webpage.

Could someone point me in the right direction to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table that stores which user is ordering the product, the time when the user started the transaction and how long the time frame should be for the user to complete the transaction. Then when displaying the products to other users, it should check whether they are the person ordering that product, and if there's currently a lock on that product.